# How to rectify the error of "self' used before 'self.init' call or assignment to 'self'"?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, model, google-cloud-firestore

I am facing the error of `self` used before `self.init` call or assignment to `self` in the below code for the model class for the tableview cell item, it happened after I tried to get document id of the table cell item.

What should be done? Please recommend.

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore


protocol DocumentSerializable  {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}


struct Post {
    var _postKey:  String!

     var _username: String!
     var _postTitle: String!
     var _postcategory:  String!
     var _postContent:  String!




    var dictionary:[String:Any] {
        return [
            "username": _username,
            "postTitle":_postTitle,
            "postcategory":_postcategory,
            "postContent":_postContent,
            "postKey":_postKey
        ]
    }

}

extension Post : DocumentSerializable {



    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {

        guard let postKey = key,
            let username = dictionary["username"] as? String,

            let postTitle = dictionary["postTitle"] as? String,
            let postcategory = dictionary["postcategory"] as? String,
            let postContent = dictionary["postContent"] as? String   else { return nil }


        self.init(_postKey: postKey, _username: username ,_postTitle: postTitle, _postcategory: postcategory, _postContent: postContent)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `guard let postKey = dictionary["postKey"] as? String`.

Comment: but then i need to get the documentID as well, how would it happen?

Comment: `documentID` _is_ `postKey`, isn't it?

Comment: no that was not correct so I edited it

Comment: can you provide general idea on how to configure the model ?

Comment: Where is `key` coming from?  Why are you using _ prefixes?  Why are your struct properties implicitly unwrapped optionals?

Answer (score 0):

You have some circular dependency going on, to access the dictionary variable you need an instance, for the instance to be created you need to call init but again to call init you should have the dictionary variable initialized and so on. You could make the dictionary variable static.